# What's the meaning of "I'm slinging mad volume and fat stacking benjies"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, slang

Recently I was watching the television show *[Breaking Bad](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/)*. There's a sentence of dialogue from [season 2, episode 6](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1232253/) that confused me:

> Jesse Pinkman: You got something for me?
>     Skinny Pete: Yeah, I found 'em.
>     Jesse Pinkman: Is this a "five" or an "S"?
>   Skinny Pete: Five, yo. No wait... S. No, no... yeah, five.
>   Jesse Pinkman: Yeah? Jesus, how the hell do you spell "street" wrong? S-T-R-E-A-T?
>   Skinny Pete: Hey, man, I'm slingin' mad volume and fat stackin' benjies, you know what I'm sayin'? I can't be all about, like, spelling and sh-t.

I am really confused as to the meaning of the last sentence, especially the words *slinging* and *stacking* here.

Comment: I am distributing very large quantities (of narcotics?) and amassing large stacks of $100 bills. (The $100 bill has a portrait of Benjamin Franklin.)

Comment: It should go without saying that this is not Standard English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Slinging = selling drugs

Mad volume = a crazy amount

Fat stacking = creating large stacks of

Benjies = $100 bills (which feature Benjamin Franklin)

Thus: I am selling a crazy amount of drugs and making a ton of money.